# Why does Spring Insight throw NulllPointerExceptions when initializing TC Server?

Tags: spring-insight

During TC Server initialization of the Insight app, it seems to instruments the deployed apps.    It starts up, and I can see results.  However, when I examine the logs, I can see 16 NullPointerExceptions like the following.  I have 16 apps deployed.  Possibly that is a coincidence:

```
[PackageClassLoader@111ead83] warning parse definitions failed -- (NullPointerException) null
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.parseDefinitions(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:264)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.DefaultWeavingContext.getDefinitions(DefaultWeavingContext.java:130)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initialize(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:155)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$ExplicitlyInitializedClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initialize(Aj.java:277)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$ExplicitlyInitializedClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.getWeavingAdaptor(Aj.java:282)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$WeaverContainer.getWeaver(Aj.java:260)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:91)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:54)
    at com.springsource.insight.weaver.InsightClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(InsightClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:51)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData$PackageClassLoader.fastFindClass(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:570)
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader$CachingLoader.load(CompositeClassLoader.java:258)
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader$CachingLoader.load(CompositeClassLoader.java:241)
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:88)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData.wire(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:405)
    at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData.wire(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:396)
    at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData.onBeforeExecute(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:237)
    at org.drools.rule.DialectRuntimeRegistry.onBeforeExecute(DialectRuntimeRegistry.java:132)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.reloadAll(PackageBuilder.java:875)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:828)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:404)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:586)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:37)
    at com.xtrac.config.util.ValidatorConfigurationFactory.buildValidator(ValidatorConfigurationFactory.java:53)
    at com.xtrac.config.validation.ValidatorTemplate.(ValidatorTemplate.java:66)
    at com.xtrac.config.validation.ProcessDrlValidatorImpl.(ProcessDrlValidatorImpl.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Does anybody know why I receive these NullPointerExceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is an issue with Drools and its custom class loader.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3122

Comment: Correct.  I upgraded Drools and the error disappeared.